# Fitting propeller to shaft

Tags: underwater

Hey I'm building an underwater robot(ROV) for a school project and I recently bought plastic propellers 55mm but sadly they came without prop adapters. Is there any easy alternative such as using epoxy glue to fit the prop on the shaft? The shaft is 3.5mm and slightly smaller than the diameter of propeller. Please help me out.

Comment: I didn't think the size of shaft and propeller mattered to understand what alternatives are possible sorry.

Comment: you could use a shaft with a threaded end ... clamp the propeller between two nuts and washers ... attach the shaft to the motor with a coupler